# Why I am keep getting list index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("../Videos/3 way traffic.mp4")  # For Video
model = YOLO("../Yolo-Weights/yolov8l.pt")
classNames = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck"]
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")
tracker = Sort(max_age=20, min_hits=3, iou_threshold=0.3)  # creating instance
trajectories = {}
p=0
q=1
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break
    imgRegion = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    results = model(imgRegion, stream=True)
    detections = np.empty((0, 5))
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            w, h = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
            conf: float = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100
            cls = int(box.cls[0])
            currentClass: Union[str, Any] = classNames[cls]
            if currentClass == "car" or currentClass == "truck" or currentClass == "bus" or currentClass == "motorbike" and conf > 0.3:
                currentArray = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2, conf])
                detections = np.vstack((detections, currentArray))
                cvzone.putTextRect(img, f' {currentClass}', (x1 + 10, y1 + 20), colorT=(255, 255, 255), colorR=(60, 20, 220), font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, scale=0.75, thickness=1, offset=2)
    resultsTracker = tracker.update(detections)
    for result in resultsTracker:
        x1, y1, x2, y2, id = result
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
        w, h = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
        cvzone.cornerRect(img, (x1, y1, w, h), l=17, t=2, rt=1, colorR=(255, 228, 181), colorC=(60, 20, 220))
        cx, cy = x1 + w // 2, y1 + h // 2
        cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        print("cx,cy :", cx,cy)
        print("id:", id)
        
        
        if id in trajectories:
            trajectories[id].extend([cx, cy])
        else:
            trajectories.update({id: [cx,cy]})
        print("Trajectories:", trajectories)

        key_number = list(trajectories.keys())
        length_dictionary = len(trajectories[id])

        if length_dictionary>=4:
            first_coordinate = trajectories[id][p]
            second_coordinate = trajectories[id][q]
            third_coordinate = trajectories[id][p + 2]
            fourth_coordinate = trajectories[id][q + 2]
            print("First coordinate:", first_coordinate)
            print("Second coordinate:", second_coordinate)
            print("Third coordinate:", third_coordinate)
            print("Fourth coordinate:", fourth_coordinate)
            p += 2
            q += 2
        else:
            pass
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code above is for drawing the trajectory lines of vehicle paths. The lines are supposed to stay there for every vehicle that has passed from the video till the end.

I was adding the coordinates of the center of each vehicle detected into a dictionary. So that I'll create lines from the coordinates of previous center points to the current center points, by taking the last four points of the value of trajectories. The trajectories dictionary of the second frame of video looks like:

```
0: 384x640 4 cars, 1 truck, 299.2ms
Speed: 15.6ms preprocess, 299.2ms inference, 0.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
cx,cy : 371 132
id: 5.0
Trajectories: {5.0: [372, 130, 371, 132], 4.0: [541, 140], 3.0: [309, 120], 2.0: [398, 348], 1.0: [249, 345]}

cx,cy : 542 141
id: 4.0
Trajectories: {5.0: [372, 130, 371, 132], 4.0: [541, 140, 542, 141], 3.0: [309, 120], 2.0: [398, 348], 1.0: [249, 345]}

cx,cy : 308 120
id: 3.0
Trajectories: {5.0: [372, 130, 371, 132], 4.0: [541, 140, 542, 141], 3.0: [309, 120, 308, 120], 2.0: [398, 348], 1.0: [249, 345]}

cx,cy : 394 358
id: 2.0
Trajectories: {5.0: [372, 130, 371, 132], 4.0: [541, 140, 542, 141], 3.0: [309, 120, 308, 120], 2.0: [398, 348, 394, 358], 1.0: [249, 345]}

cx,cy : 244 352
id: 1.0
Trajectories: {5.0: [372, 130, 371, 132], 4.0: [541, 140, 542, 141], 3.0: [309, 120, 308, 120], 2.0: [398, 348, 394, 358], 1.0: [249, 345, 244, 352]}
```

Problem starts when I try to retrive the co ordinates. It only gives the co ordinates of first id and from the second id it shows following error:

> third_coordinate = trajectories[id][p + 2]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried putting p+=2 after the else statement like below:

```
        else:
            pass
    p += 2
    q += 2
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But the same error appears. The only thing that resolves the error is by removing the p & q incremental lines but then it is only picking the first 4 values instead of the last.

Comment: It makes sense since you define p and q outside of the cycle and them increase them inside, by the second loop `p=2, q=3` and `p+2` is outside of your list's range. What's not clear is what you're trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate? Why not just use `trajectories[id][0], ..., trajectories[id][3]`

Comment: @MariaK I want to draw trajectory lines from where the vehicle is passing. The lines were supposed to stay on the image even after the vehicle passed from the video so that a pattern of trajectories would be obtained on the last frame of the vehicle.
To achieve this I suppose I would have to gather coordinates of all points from exactly where the vehicle passed, that's why I want to extract the last four points from the list in the dictionary to draw the next section of the line. The 'trajectories[id][0]' will only return the value at place 0 while the list is constantly increasing.

Comment: but  4.0: [541, 140],  the second id has only 2 co ordinates , so no prob , its working fine